# Thingsbaord esp32-ota update failed

Tags: thingsboard, ota

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogblt.png)

Getting this error ?? am using thingsbaord cloud account for ESP32-ota ..using sample code provideed by thingsbaord with server_certs..when new firmware bin v1.2 (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thingsboard/esp32-ota/master/firmware/example-v1.2.bin).then it shows certificate error